# Why aren't props passed down to child?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following code in my render function where I'm trying to pass the user as props to the `<Client />` component. When I check to see which props `<Client />` received its only history, location and match. `this.props.test = undefined`

```
const users = this.state.users;
  return (
    <TableBody>
        {users.map((user, i) => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={i}>
              <TableCell>
                <Link to={`/Users/${user.name}`}>{user.name}</Link>
                <Route
                  path={`/Users/${user.name}`}
                  render={props => <Client {...props} test="hi" />}
                />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{user.jobTitle}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{user.company.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{user.status}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
      )
```

Comment: No need in `user` arg in render callback: `() => <Client user={user} />`

Comment: ok, but it still doesnt solve my problem. here is how Client comp looks like `class Client extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { name } = this.props.match.params;
    return <div>{name}</div>;
  }
}

export default Client;`